# What does "region" and "polygon" mean in rasterize function from raster library in R?

Tags: r, polygon, raster, rasterize

When I use the function rasterize from the raster library in R, this message appears in the console:

```
"Found 6085 region(s) and 6409 polygon(s)".
```

There is 6085 polygons in the shapefile, so I was wondering what does these two terms mean ?

Answer (score 3):

A polygon is a set of points (vertices) connected to each other in a certain way by lines (edges). A region is one abstraction level higher in that sense that a region consists of one or more polygons.